# KeySpoof Python

Tags: python

хочу написать такую штуку как KeySpoof, если кто не знает, это когда нажимаешь например на q, а пишется другая буква, так вот, как такое сотворить? именно чтобы писалась не q,а k (это пример), желательно,чтобы я нажимал рандом буквы,а писались данные в аргументах a b c d e
вот мой код:

````
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
def on_release(key):
    if keyvvod == True:
        print('{0} release'.format(key))
        if keyid == 1:
            shell.SendKeys(a)
            keyid = keyid + 1
            print(keyid)
        elif keyid == 2:
            shell.SendKeys(b)
            keyid = keyid + 1
        elif keyid == 3:
            shell.SendKeys(c)
            keyid = keyid + 1
        elif keyid == 4:
            shell.SendKeys(d)
            keyid = keyid + 1
        elif keyid == 5:
            shell.SendKeys(e)
            keyid = keyid + 1
        elif keyid == 6:
            shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
            keyid = 0
        else:
            return

    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        print("Stop")
        return False


# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()  ```
````

Comment: Код не рабочий. Логическая переменная "keyvvod"  не определена.

Comment: этот код был вырезан с рабочего кода, у рабочего кода в начале указано,что keyid = 0
keyvvod = True

Comment: обычно from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener  используется в начале кода))
ну если придерживаться принятых правил кодирования

Comment: я знаю, я просто вырезал функцию и залил сюда, у меня 2 функции, в 1 в ее конце keyid = 1, у меня такое ощущение, что как при запуске скрипта, функция загрузилась, так больше она и не обновляется, тк после if keyid == 1: действия вообще не происходит

Comment: попробовал с потоком, ничего хорошего не получилось

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать словари
keys_dict = {old_key_1 : new_key_1, old_key_2 : new_key_2}
и просто написать shell.SendKeys(keys_dict.get(key))

Comment: а точнее можно? и желательно с кодом, заранее спасибо)

Comment: a b c d e это уже агрументы с данными

Answer (score 0):

Следующий код заменяет нажатие буквенных клавиш на случайные. Кнопки типа <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> пропускаются как есть.

```
# pip install keyboard
import keyboard
from string import ascii_letters
from random import choice

def send_random_key():
    key = choice(ascii_letters)
    print('New key: ', key)
    keyboard.send(key)


def hook(event):
    if not event.name in ascii_letters:
        return event
    print('Blocked: ', event)
    send_random_key()


keyboard.hook(callback=hook, suppress=True)
keyboard.wait()

# Blocked:  KeyboardEvent(l up)
# New key:  o
# Blocked:  KeyboardEvent(l down)
# New key:  J
# Blocked:  KeyboardEvent(l up)
# New key:  G
```

Comment: да, это работает, только хотелось бы, чтобы вместо рандома, он писал буквы из a b c d e последовательно, типо 1 нажатие - он пишет a, потом 2 нажатие - он пишет b и тд)
и как сделать, что если хук видит нажатие на shift и e вместе, то он их не блочит

Comment: вопрос актуален, можешь помочь?

Comment: @полнаянулинаотвечаю описал ведь общий способ, изменяйте как вам нужно